# Move unread Gmail messages to other label

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, automation

Basically my company uses Gmail to manage all its emails. Emails are assigned to a user using labels.

Is it possible that if a message if assigned to a label and is not read that it can be moved to another label?

Example:

Email comes in

Assigned to @Matt

Matt is out of the office so it does not get read within specified time

Messages should then be assigned to @John

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Filters only work on messages as they come in, so what you want can't be automated with just Gmail. To do what you want you'd have to save the URL for a custom search and run it once in a while.

A search for `label:@Matt is:unread` will find all of the conversations you're looking for. Then you simply select them all and move them as needed. You can even put time ranges in the search, such as `older_than:7d` (which finds messages that are older than seven days).

If you enable the "Quick Links" lab, it will add a "widget" to your Gmail sidebar in which you can add virtually any link you want, including the link that results from your search: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#apps/label%3A%40Matt+is%3Aunread`.

To automate it as you'd like would require a third-party tool.